# Publish 2 Xunit result in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I`m trying to publish 2 Xunit result in my pipeline in Jenkins

My first publish test result works well.
Why my second test result doesn`t fail my build?
In test report, I see all my failed test (second and first)

For check test status i try to use ${currentBuild.result} and ${currentBuild.currentResult}

My Pipe:

```
 stage('Run Unit Tests') {
   build('UnitTests')
  }
  stage('Publish Test Result') {
   step([$class: 'XUnitPublisher', testTimeMargin: '3000', thresholdMode:
    2,
    thresholds: [
     [$class: 'FailedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '', failureThreshold: '0', unstableNewThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: ''],
     [$class: 'SkippedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '', failureThreshold: '0', unstableNewThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: '']
    ],
    tools: [
     [$class: 'XUnitDotNetTestType', deleteOutputFiles: true, failIfNotNew: true, pattern: '\\**\\unittests-results.xml', skipNoTestFiles: false, stopProcessingIfError: true]
    ]
   ])
  }
  stage('Run Integration Tests') {
   build('IntegrationTests')
  }
  stage('Publish Integration Test Result') {
   step([$class: 'XUnitPublisher', testTimeMargin: '3000', thresholdMode: 2,
    thresholds: [
     [$class: 'FailedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '', failureThreshold: '0', unstableNewThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: ''],
     [$class: 'SkippedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '', failureThreshold: '0', unstableNewThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: '']
    ],
    tools: [
     [$class: 'XUnitDotNetTestType', deleteOutputFiles: true, failIfNotNew: true, pattern: '\\**\\**\\integrationtests-results.xml', skipNoTestFiles: false, stopProcessingIfError: true]
    ]
   ])
  }
```

Comment: I know this is old but I'm running into this now.  I noticed in my current run that it's still looking at the path from the first xunit step